# Does reading data from a UI thread require invoke?

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading

I understand that updating the UI from another thread requires an invoke, but is an invoke also required when just reading data from the UI?

For example, if running a calculation based on data found in a large grid, do you need to invoke the grid when reading the values found in the grid and assigning them to the variables used in the calculation?

If not, why not?

Is so, are there performance issues? Is it better to cache all the data to an array (or datatable) and then run the calculations or to invoke the grid each time the data is read (for example, at each row)?

I'm specifically asking about VB.NET, though I doubt there's much difference in any of the other .NET languages.

Comment: You should not be asking this question.  What value do you expect to get when your thread reads the property at a completely random point in time?  Could be anything when you allow the user to continue editing the grid content.  Could be a half-entered value.  You'll exclaim "I'll disable the grid!"  Yes, that's a good idea.  But then you don't have to solve this problem anymore since you can simply read the values you need *before* you start the thread.

Comment: You are right, I can read the grid before running it, hence I asked about performance between the two methods if invoke is not required. However, why read the values into another table in memory if the table on the UI already contains the values? This is burdensome and time consuming for large tables.

Comment: UI is not a "table".  Separating the data from the view is a universal programming approach with many benefits.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but is the datagridviewselectedrowcollection not on the UI thread? I'm pulling from that collection to see which items the user has selected to analyze. I can access the main datatable behind the grid, but that doesn't tell me which items the user has selected. And as I said before, the selection list is large so copying the selected items to a separate table is not my first choice if avoidable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the control, some may let you read from a non UI thread some may not.

The best solution to the problem is don't read directly from the control, have some backing object that holds the data and then using binding to have the control use the data from the backing object. This is the basic premise behind [MVVM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx) (Model, View, View Model), a very popular pattern in WPF, but is also useable in Winforms.

Answer (score 0):

No. The invoke is required to update the UI because the UI can only be updated from the foreground thread.  There is no restriction about which thread can read data.